# Tooltip for disabled TabItem

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm wanting to have a tooltip for disabled TabItems in a TabControl. The standard way of putting tooltips onto disabled controls in Silverlight is by wrapping the control in a dummy element that has the tooltip, but I can't get at the TabItem like that. The TabItems' host control is a TabPanel, which doesn't seem to expose any useful properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround for my own problem:

I've got a TabControl Behavior that finds the "TabPanelTop" template part (or left, right, or bottom depending on TabStripPlacement), along with the "TemplateTop". I add a Canvas into the TemplateTop (which is a Grid), and fill it with Transparent Rectangles whose positions (using TransformToVisual) and sizes are calculated (and updated) to be the same as the TabItems, which are the children of the TabPanelTop.

The visibility of the Rectangles is bound to the inverse of TabItem IsEnabled, and the ToolTipService.ToolTip is bound to the ToolTipService.ToolTip on the TabItem.

It's a bit scary but it works and is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with putting a Toolip on a disabled menu item, i solved it by changing the VisualState of my menu item to Disabled and then disabling the MouseButton events.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(tabitem, "Disabled", true);
```

You'll have to be careful with other events though, because the VisualState will change according to different events. It's not a perfect solution, but it will work for certain scenarios.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm, interesting. As you say, it could be a bit dangerous.